# InputObject is null - Powershell DataTable

Tags: powershell, datatable

I'm attempting to output an object array (of event logs) to a DataTable with the expectation to pipe into SQL.

The basics are:

- Get some forwarded events
- Process them to pull some required info out
- Output to a data table

  ```
  function Get-Type 
  { 
      param($type) 

  $types = @( 
  'System.Boolean', 
  'System.Byte[]', 
  'System.Byte', 
  'System.Char', 
  'System.Datetime', 
  'System.Decimal', 
  'System.Double', 
  'System.Guid', 
  'System.Int16', 
  'System.Int32', 
  'System.Int64', 
  'System.Single', 
  'System.UInt16', 
  'System.UInt32', 
  'System.UInt64') 

      if ( $types -contains $type ) { 
          Write-Output "$type" 
      } 
      else { 
          Write-Output 'System.String' 

      } 
  } #Get-Type 

  function Out-DataTable
  { 
      [CmdletBinding()] 
      param([Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [PSObject[]]$InputObject) 

      Begin 
      { 
          $dt = new-object Data.datatable   
          $First = $true  
      } 
      Process 
      { 
          Write-Output "test"
          foreach ($object in $InputObject) 
          { 
              $DR = $DT.NewRow()
              foreach($property in $object.PsObject.get_properties()) 
              {   
                  if ($first) 
                  {   
                      $Col =  new-object Data.DataColumn   
                      $Col.ColumnName = $property.Name.ToString()   
                      if ($property.value) 
                      { 
                          if ($property.value -isnot [System.DBNull]) { 
                              $Col.DataType = [System.Type]::GetType("$(Get-Type $property.TypeNameOfValue)") 
                           } 
                      } 
                      $DT.Columns.Add($Col) 
                  }   
                  if ($property.Gettype().IsArray) { 
                      $DR.Item($property.Name) =$property.value | ConvertTo-XML -AS String -NoTypeInformation -Depth 1 
                  }   
                 else { 
                      $DR.Item($property.Name) = $property.value 
                  } 
              }   
              $DT.Rows.Add($DR)   
              $First = $false 
          } 
      }  

      End 
      { 
          Write-Output @(,($dt)) 
      } 

  } #Out-DataTable

  $allEvents = Get-WinEvent -LogName ForwardedEvents | Where-Object{$_.Id -ne 111}

  $outEvents = @()
  $dt = $null

  foreach ($curEvent in $allEvents){
      $curObj = $null
      switch ($curEvent.ID) {
          4624    { 
                  $curObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TimeCreated -Value ([datetime]$curEvent.TimeCreated)
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Action -Value $curEvent.TaskDisplayName
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MachineName -Value $curEvent.MachineName 
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[36]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LoginID -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[40]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SourceIP -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[64]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $curEvent.Id
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecordID -Value $curEvent.RecordID
                  }
          4647    { 
                  $curObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TimeCreated -Value ([datetime]$curEvent.TimeCreated)
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Action -Value $curEvent.TaskDisplayName
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MachineName -Value $curEvent.MachineName 
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[8]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LoginID -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[12]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SourceIP -Value "Not Available"
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $curEvent.Id
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecordID -Value $curEvent.RecordID
                  }
          4778    { 
                  $curObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TimeCreated -Value ([datetime]$curEvent.TimeCreated)
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Action -Value "Reconnect"
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MachineName -Value $curEvent.MachineName 
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[6]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LoginID -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[10]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SourceIP -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[24]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $curEvent.Id
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecordID -Value $curEvent.RecordID
                  }
          4800    { 
                  $curObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TimeCreated -Value ([datetime]$curEvent.TimeCreated)
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Action -Value "Locked"
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MachineName -Value $curEvent.MachineName 
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[8]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LoginID -Value ((($curEvent.Message).Split([Environment]::NewLine)[12]).split(":")[1]).Trim()
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SourceIP -Value "Not Available"
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $curEvent.Id
                  Add-Member -InputObject $curObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecordID -Value $curEvent.RecordID
                  }

          Default { }
      }
      $outEvents += $curObj

  }

  $outEvents
  $dt = Out-DataTable -InputObject $outEvents
  ```

When I run this, the last output of $outEvents lists all of the event objects with the correct details however trying to pipt it into Out-DataTable returns:

```
Out-DataTable : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At \\server\scripts\Repository\Write-UserLoginEvent\Write-UserLoginEvent.ps1:140 char:38
+     $dt = Out-DataTable -InputObject $outEvents
+                                      ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-DataTable], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Out-DataTable
```

I've tried all different methods of formatting the data etc and I can't seem to get this function to accept my custom object array.

If I use a built in function like 'Get-Process' the function works correctly and returns the DataTable so I'm thinking it is something specific to the object I'm returning.

EDIT: Before I posted this, I also moved the DataTable segment into the loop, to attempt to print each event object as an individual DataTable. Hoping to identify where the issue was. It failed immediately on the first object.

Comment: In your code block, the last line is `$dt = Out-DataTable -InputObject $outEvents`, but in your error it's `$dt = Out-DataTable -InputObject $curObj`. Seems like there is a typo at some point?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I was testing something out (putting the out-table within the loop) which is why the variable doesn't match. I'll add that to the OP because that raises some more info, it doesn't work that way either!

Comment: *sigh* you put me on the right track, made me look at it another way. I'll put a proper answer in but thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I had an un-captured event type that had slipped through.

Because this event was not being formatted correctly there was a single event in the output that would not fit into the DataTable structure, causing the NULL error.

To identify the issue I put an Out-DataTable step inside the loop to process each object individually and in the output I could see that all objects succeeded except one. Tracking down that one I could see that I hadn't catered for that Event ID (8001).